# How to create Host-only Networks in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I follow below steps to create host-only Networks in ubuntu 14.04(with UI)

```
   Clicks “File” from the menu
   Clicks “Preferences…”
   Clicks “Host-only Networks”, then clicks the + icon to create a new adapter
   Set IPV4 address to be 1.1.1.1
```

Where can I found those items? I only saw "files" in ubuntu .

BTW:　I use

"VirtualBox 5.0.20Ubuntu 14.04 ("Trusty") / 14.10 ("Utopic") / 15.04 ("Vivid") AMD64"

Answer (score 0):

I already got answer, maybe duplicate with other questions.  User "Ctrl+G" to open global virtualbox setting in ubuntu, and select "Network" menu. You can create host only networks here.